# Can IIS host a site with only a net.tcp binding

Tags: wcf, iis-8, nettcpbinding

I would like to create a web site in IIS that hosts a WCF service using net.tcp binding. Since there is no need for the http binding, I would like to remove this. However, if I remove the http binding (and leave only the net.tcp binding) from the IIS manager, the site appears with a red X on top of it, and there are no longer an option to Start/Stop the site in the context menu.

If I try using the PowerShell cmdlets `Start-Website` or `Stop-website` I get the error message: "*The object identifier does not represent a valid object. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800710D8)*".

Is it not possible to have a site with only a net.tcp binding in IIS? Do I really need to reserve a port for http, even though it won't be used, or is there some configuration option I am missing here?